# fill in listview using textbox c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I wanted to fill out a treeview we use a textbox but I have a problem I can’t save

how to display the text field enter in a textbox in a treeviews.

attach the XAML code and the C# code that allows me to complete the treeviws.

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0">
            <TabControl Margin="0,0,0,24" Name="SideTabControl" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}">


                <TabItem Name="OutlineTabItem" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsSelected="True">

                    <TreeView Name="bookmark_tree" RenderTransformOrigin="0.741,2.29" >
                        <TextBox x:Name ="txtBookmarkName" Margin="0,0,0,0" KeyDown="TxtBookmarkName_OnKeyDown" Visibility="Hidden" />

                    </TreeView>

                    <TabItem.Header>
                        <Image Source="../../Shared/Resources/IconImage/signet.png" Height="14" OpacityMask="#FFF0410E"
                       ToolTipService.ShowDuration="2000"/>
                    </TabItem.Header>

                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip Placement="Bottom">
                            <TextBlock Text="Liste des Signets"/>
                        </ToolTip>
                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>

                </TabItem>

            </TabControl>

/// <summary>
    /// Méthode permettre l'ajoute d'un signet à une page d'un document.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Objet</param>
    /// <param name="e">Evenement</param>
    private void bookmark_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {



         txtBookmarkName.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
         txtBookmarkName.Focus();

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Méthode permettre de Remplissez le contrôle d'arborescence de signets avec des éléments de signets.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">Signet à ajouter.</param>
    /// <param name="nodes">Liste des items.</param>
    static void BuildBookmarkTree(Bookmark item, ItemCollection nodes)
    {
        for (int i = 0; item.IsValid(); item = item.GetNext(), ++i)
        {
            TreeViewItem new_node = new TreeViewItem();
            new_node.Header = item.GetTitle();
            ToolTipService.SetToolTip(new_node, new_node.Header);
            nodes.Add(new_node);
            new_node.Tag = item;

            if (item.IsOpen()) new_node.IsExpanded = true;
            if (item.HasChildren()) // Ajouter récursivement des sous-arbres d'enfants
            {
                BuildBookmarkTree(item.GetFirstChild(), new_node.Items);
            }
        }
    }
 private void TxtBookmarkName_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {


        if (e.Key == Key.Return)
        {
            // Récupère le document actuel
            //PDFDoc doc = PdfViewer.GetDoc();
            PDFDoc doc = this.PdfViewWpf.CurrentDocument;

            // Lock document
            PdfViewer.DocLock(true);




            // Permet de créér d'abord les éléments favoris du signet.
            string bookmarkName = txtBookmarkName.Text + ":" + PdfViewer.GetCurrentPage().ToString();
            Bookmark myBookmark = pdftron.PDF.Bookmark.Create(doc, bookmarkName);



            // Ajouter le signet à la racine.
            doc.AddRootBookmark(myBookmark);

            // Nous pouvons maintenant associer de nouveaux signets à des destinations de page:
            Destination bookmark_destination = Destination.CreateFit(doc.GetPage(PdfViewer.GetCurrentPage()));
            myBookmark.SetAction(pdftron.PDF.Action.CreateGoto(bookmark_destination));

            // Ajout pour actualiser l'arborescence de la visionneuse.
            BuildBookmarkTree(myBookmark, bookmark_tree.Items);


            // Unlock the document after we are done
            PdfViewer.DocUnlock();

            PdfViewHelper.Save(this.PdfViewer, doc);

            txtBookmarkName.Text = string.Empty;

        }
    }
```

[image shows the result when I use textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUNsI.jpg)

[Result after closing and opening the application again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJvsF.jpg)

Comment: Just checking I understand the question correctly. Currently your giving the bookmarks a prefix ("Mon signet sur la  page: ") followed by the page number, but you want to have a text box so you can enter your own custom prefix? Like a Dialog?

Comment: @JacobJAShanks ,  Yes, that’s what I wanted to do.               Please, do you have an example of a code that allows me to do this?

Comment: I have placed an answer below for one way you could do this, but ultimately what your trying to do is to get a string into the routine. There are many ways of doing this depending on what you want to do. My way is a suggestion.

Comment: So the issue isn't with the ListView not being updated with new bookmarks in runtime, but that's its not saving them to the pdf so they reappear after relaunching the app?

Comment: If the bookmarks are added to the PDF doc, if I put the textbox in dors of listeviews, I see the bookmarks that are added to the PDF doc.     <TreeView Name="bookmark_tree" RenderTransformOrigin="0.741,2.29" >
                            <!--<TextBox x:Name ="txtBookmarkName" Margin="0,0,0,0" KeyDown="TxtBookmarkName_OnKeyDown" Visibility="Hidden" />-->

                        </TreeView>

Comment: I remain at your disposal for further information.

Comment: Perhaps try making the textbox it's own element instead of embedding it in the ListView. Try just floating it over the top

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I now manage to post my bookmarks in my listeviews.

Comment: That's great news, what did you do in the end to fix it?

Comment: I put the textbox to the tableControl outside which contains my Views list.                      </TabItem>

                </TabControl>

                <TextBox x:Name ="txtBookmarkName"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  KeyDown="TxtBookmarkName_OnKeyDown" Visibility="Hidden"  
                         Height="16" Width="78" Margin="58,2,0,0"  FontSize="11">

                </TextBox>

Comment: That makes sense, if my answer was helpful would you mind marking it as the answer?

Comment: please, can you tell me how to delete a text in a listviews in C #?

Comment: If your looking to add and remove from your ListView, you may need to look into a slightly different solution involving something like an [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2). You would put your 'text' into this collection which behaves like a list, then set the ItemSource of your ListView to this ObservableCollection. Changes made to it (i.e. add, edit or remove) will be sent back to the UI and displayed to the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are plenty of ways of getting a custom string in, it just depends on what you want to achieve and how it works nicely in your UI.

From the screenshot I saw, one way that I think you'd could do it seamlessly would be to trigger a `TextBox` to be visible below the bookmark button upon clicking it. The box would have keyboard focus upon it being visible so you can type the bookmark title you want easily and upon pressing 'return' it would trigger the event handler you already have, just replace:

```cs
string bookmarkName = "Mon signet sur la  page: " + 
        PdfViewer.GetCurrentPage().ToString();
```

With

```cs
txtBookmarkName.Text + ": " +
        PdfViewer.GetCurrentPage().ToString();
txtBookmarkName.Text = string.Empty();
```

**Some code examples below:**

XAML for the text box:

```xml
<TextBox x:Name"txtBookmarkName" Margin="0,0,0,0" KeyDown="TxtBookmarkName_OnKeyDown" Visibility="Hidden"/>
```

(Margin values are placeholders, you'll need to change these to position and size the box according to your UI)

Event handler for the text box:

```cs
private void TxtBookmarkName_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    txtBookmarkName.Visible = false;    

    if (e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        //Run bookmark_Click Event Handler Code
    }
}
```

(You may wish to add a condition for if Escape is pressed to cancel the text box as well as an event for if the text box has lost focus)

Code for your bookmark button so that the TextBox can be made visible and gets focus:

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtBookmarkName.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    txtBookmarkName.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Okay so that looks like the actual code is working but its not updating the UI after finishing. How are you updating your tree view, could you update the question with that code or provide a link to it?

Comment: @Ali thanks for posting your XAML but it may not be suitable to post it as an answer, possibly update your question. Could you perhaps update the question with the code you use to build and update the tree view?